# Howto avoid journald entry for one program?

Tags: log, systemd-journald

On my Ubuntu-MATE Clevo laptop there is the program [N151ZU-fan-controller](https://gitlab.com/francois.kneib/clevo-N151ZU-fan-controller) that logging a message 2 times by second.

I filtered it in rsyslog configuration in /etc/rsyslog.d/10-N151ZU-fan-controller.conf `with line :programname, contains, "N151ZU-fan-controller" stop`

But I could not find howto filter it's logs in journald (systemd-journald) ? *2 lines by second take much volume on disk ...*

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to redirect stdout to null with option `StandardOutput` in service configuration file.

Like

```
# /etc/systemd/system/N151ZU-fan-controller.service
...
[Service]
...
StandardOutput=null
...
```

Source: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#id-1.17