# How to disable journald for vlc player

Tags: systemd, vlc, wayland, systemd-journald

My system is constantly crashing because of `systemd-journald` going into overdrive and bogging down the CPU (and probably the disk as well) when I watch videos with `VLC`. I notice this behavior getting triggered by hitting the Pause/Play button. At this point I have no clue how to rescue the system, I'm just simply forced to do a hard reset, which is very annoying and time consuming.

I'd like to completely disable VLC from messing with `systemd-journald`. I have seen a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188148/howto-avoid-journald-entry-for-one-program) but the provided solution didn't work for me.

This is how I adapted the answer above: I created a file named `vlc.service` in `/etc/systemd/system`
with this content:

```
[Service]
StandardOutput=null
```

System variables:

- Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop
- VLC version 3.0.16 Vetinari (3.0.13-8-g41878ff4f2)
- systemd 249 (249.11-0ubuntu3.1)

In VLC itself, logging to syslog is not enabled (See screenshot)

[image]

Comment: Are you sure system log is the culprit? If you disabled from VLC preference shouldn't be an issue anymore. The same happen with mplayer?

Comment: Do you have a sample message from `systemd-journald` coming from `vlc`? I assume, that the problem is not the logging by systemd, but some kernel related error messages. Run vlc and run `sudo dmesg` in parallel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root cause of the issue was the half-baked `Wayland` protocol, and disabling it entirely got rid of the whole problem.

Steps:

- Edit `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` to include the line `WaylandEnable=false`.
- Restart GDM3 with `sudo systemctl restart gdm3`

Comment: +1; Yes "the half-baked Wayland protocol" is causing several problems. It should not be default in an LTS version.

Answer (score 1):

By default systemd forwards every standard output (stdout) and error (stderr) message to the journal.

Vlc isn't designed for this and sent too many messages problably on the standard output.

To stop this behaviour:
Edit your service

```
sudo systemctl edit vlc.service
```

Add the following:

```
[Service]
StandardOutput=null
#StandardError=null
```

Remove the # above for also silencing the error output.

Restart the service:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart vlc.service
```

Comment: Funny how this works... *this* is the correct answer to the question that was asked, but it didn't solve the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run vlc from a terminal and redirect the output to /dev/null ?

`vlc <file> > /dev/null 2>&1`

If the issue persist it could be an error comming from the video driver causing crash.
Check systemd-journal after the crash to see if some driver/package is involved in the issue